# Complex Formula in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I have a 'dashboard' sheet and a 'log' sheet. I'm trying to pull data from the 'log' sheet and perform calculations on the data before displaying it in the 'dashboard' sheet. The 'log' sheet will have several hundred rows of data. Inside of the log sheet is a column for 'Task' and I will be using the data in the 'Task' column to locate other data that is related to the specific task.

**The Problem**

I'm trying to locate all of the instances of a specific activity, gather the hours spent on the activity (1 column to left), and then add up the total time spent on the activity (all instances) before displaying the total in the 'dashboard' sheet.

I've done a little reading about the DSUM and ArraySum, but I really don't know where to start with this problem. I know I can create new sheets for every 'task', populate the individual sheets using a QUERY statement, perform the necessary calculations in the individual sheets, and then pull data into the dashboard sheet. But I'm wondering if there is a single formula that I can use to accomplish my goal.

**Links**

[This is the document I'm working with](https://docs.google.com/a/guhsd.net/spreadsheets/d/13um9GW8jT2DkWh1MRQ4kOohdexOFAlwxTqKDt4_11-0/edit).

[Here is a video that explains the data needed and the problem I'm trying to solve.](http://youtu.be/8OAcoqZ_vXQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered by @pnuts on another forum.

> In Dashboard D36 please enter:
>
> =sumif(log!C:C,A36,log!B:B)   (should result in the 19 you mentioned) and then copy up to D4.